# How to handle an intent in iOS when my app is closed?

Tags: ios, swift

I changed my app to de scene-approach. Before handling an intent was done correctly, but after changing to the scene-approach the code doesn't work anymore. I found out that I need to implement the handling in willConnectTo:

```swift
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    //opdrachten afhandeler: App opened from closed state
    logger.i("willConnectTo()")
    guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    for activity in connectionOptions.userActivities {
        if activity.activityType == "SpeelRadiostationAfIntent" {
            logger.i("speelRadiostationAfIntent started")
            //doesn't work somehow?
            guard let intent = userActivity?.interaction?.intent as? SpeelRadiostationAfIntent,
            let naam = intent.radiostation else {
                return    
            }
            //The above doesn't work; it returns 
            triggerdStationsname = naam
            isTriggerdFromRecentAfgespeeldOrSiri = true
        }       
    }
}
```

I need to get the name of the radiostation from the intent. But that's not handled correctly somehow.

I appreciate your help ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I made a mistake in the code:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    //opdrachten afhandeler: App opened from closed state
    logger.i("willConnectTo()")
    guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    for activity in connectionOptions.userActivities {
        if activity.activityType == "SpeelRadiostationAfIntent" {
            logger.i("speelRadiostationAfIntent started")
            //doesn't work somehow?
            guard let intent = activity.interaction?.intent as? SpeelRadiostationAfIntent,
            let naam = intent.radiostation else {
                return    
            }
            //The above doesn't work; it returns 
            triggerdStationsname = naam
            isTriggerdFromRecentAfgespeeldOrSiri = true
        }       
    }
}
```

This line was changed:

```
guard let intent = activity.interaction?.intent as? SpeelRadiostationAfIntent,
```